# Removing SKNodes in SpriteKit(Swift3)

Tags: sknode

I'm making a game similar to Flappy Bird. When my hero collides with some coins spawning randomly on the screen, I want the coins to be removed from the screen. I've tried a bunch of different stuff I've read, but nothing has worked so far. I know that "coins.removeFromParent()" is probably the way to go. And it should probably be placed in the "didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact {", but from here i haven't solved the problem.

- Do I need both of the codes in the images below or can I make both into one? Could this be the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it needs to be placed in "didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact {" and .removeFromParent() is also right. The missing element is that you need first to use the contact variable within the didBegin function to identify the node that you want to remove.

I imagine the code you want will be something like this. (This will need to be within your didBegin function.)

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.coins.rawValue {

        print("body A is the coin")

        contact.bodyA.node!.removeFromParent()

      } else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.coins.rawValue {

        print("body B is the coin")

        contact.bodyB.node!.removeFromParent()

      }
```